# Why are Spock Speck tests so wordy?

Tags: grails-2.0, spock, spock-reports

Coming from JUnit background I don't really understand the point of all the text in spockD tests, since they don't show on the output from the test.

So for example, if I have a constraint on a field Double foo with constraints foo max:5, nullable:false

And I write tests like this:

```
void "test constraints" {
   when: "foo set to > max"
     foo=6D
   then: "max validation fails"
     !foo.validate()
   when: "foo is null
     foo=null
   then: "null validation fails"
     !foo.validate()
}
```

The test is well documented in its source, but if the validation fails, the error output doesn't take advantage of all this extra typing I've done to make my tests clear.

All I get is

```
Failure:  |
test constraints(com.grapevine.FooSpec)
 |
Condition not satisfied:
f.validate()
| |
| false
```

But I can't tell form this report whether it failed the null constraint or the max constraint validation and I then need to check the line  number of the failure in the test source.

At least with JUnit I could do

```
foo=60D;
assertFalse("contraints failed to block foo>max", f.validate());
foo=null;
assertFalse("contraints failed to block foo=null", f.validate());
```

And then I'd get useful info back from in the failure report.  Which seems to both more concise and gives a more informative test failure report.

Is there some way get more robust error reporting out of Spec that take advantage of all this typing of when and then clauses so they show up on failure reports so you know what actually fails? Are these "when" and "then" text descriptors only serving as internal source documentation or are they used somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

Block descriptions are mostly meant for higher-level tests; they are rarely used in unit tests. That said, there are several third-party reporting extensions for Spock:

- https://github.com/damage-control/report
- https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports
- https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-spock-adaptor
- https://github.com/chanwit/spock-report-html

At least some of these will output block descriptions as well. Furthermore, it's planned to ship advanced reporting out-of-the-box with the next Spock version.

Instead of having one test check two unrelated cases (as in your Spock/JUnit example), it's generally better to have a separate test with a descriptive name for each case. Spock's data-driven tests can help with this.

While it's possible to add a description for a Spock condition (e.g. `assert 1 == 2, "not quite"`), I almost always prefer the default "power assert" output.

To answer your title question, well-written Spock tests are typically a lot *less* wordy than JUnit tests.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting the impression that somehow I am overdoing it the way i wrote this unit test.  What would be the efficient way to do it?

Comment: Peter already advised on that. Split your example test method into two separate methods (two tests) giving appropriate method name to each. You can skip block descriptions inside of the test then.